# make bilingual or trilingual LaTeX document

Tags: two-column, multicolumn

How do I make a bilingual (two-column) or trilingual (three-column) LaTeX document?

E.g.:

```
| Original language | Translation 1 | Translation 2 |
|                   |               |               |
|                   |               |               |
```

Also, paragraphs from each language must align vertically properly, too.

thanks

Comment: Do you mean one language in one column to show translated text beneath the original text?  Perhaps a good idea to explain a little bit more what you have and what you want?

Comment: Perhaps the best way is to use a `tabular` environment with three columns.  Regarding the language, just load all of them with `babel`.

Comment: Perhaps you want to take a look at packages like »[paracol](http://ctan.org/pkg/paracol)«, »[parallel](http://ctan.org/pkg/parallel)« or  »[parcolumns](http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns)« and other possible [packages for parallel typesetting](http://ctan.org/topic/parallel).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [paracol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) package. Once loaded, you can execute commands such as

```
 \begin{paracol}{3} % specify three columns...
 <text in first column>
 \switchcolumn
 <text in next column>
 \switchcolumn
 <text in next column>
 \switchcolumn 
 <text in next, i.e., first column>
 ...
 \end{paracol}
```