# page change in a two column table

Tags: tables

I would like to create a two column table. On the left, I put the French text and the right for the English translation. But I have a problem that the text on each column is very long. Is there a simple way to change page automatically instead of manually inserting `//`?

---

```
\begin{tabular}{p{.50\textwidth}|p{.50\textwidth}}
  \hline
1. Il y a plus de 50 ans que l'ingénieur Heaviside introduisit 
ses règles de calcul symbolique, dans un mémoire audacieux où des
calculs mathématiques fort peu justifiés sont utilisés pour la solution
de problèmes de physique. Ce calcul symbolique, ou opérationnel,
n'a cessé de se développer depuis, et sert de base aux études théoriques
des électriciens. Les ingénieurs l'utilisent systématiquement,
chacun avec sa conception personnelle, avec la conscience plus ou
moins tranquille; c'est devenu une technique « qui n'est pas rigoureuse
mais qui réussit bien ». Depuis l'introduction par Dirac de
la fameuse fonction $\delta(x)$, qui serait nulle partout sauf pour $x=0$ et
serait infinie pour $x=0$ de telle sorte que $\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}}\delta(x)\ dx=+1$, les
formules du calcul symbolique sont devenues encore plus inacceptables pour la rigueur des mathématiciens. Ecrire que la fonction
d'Heaviside $Y(x)$ égale à o pour $x<0$ et à 1 pour $x\geq 0$ a pour
dérivée la fonction de Dirac $\delta(x)$ dont la définition même est mathématiquement contradictoire, et parler des dérivées $\delta'(x), \delta'(x)$, ...
de cette fonction dénuée d'existence réelle, c'est dépasser les limites
qui nous sont permises. Comment expliquer le succès de ces méthodes?
Quand une telle situation contradictoire se présente, il
est bien rare qu'il n'en résulte pas une théorie mathématique
nouvelle qui justifie, sous une forme modifiée, le langage des
physiciens ; il y a même là une source importante de progrès des
mathématiques et de la physique. En fait de nombreuses justifications
du calcul symbolique ont été réalisées ; les principales sont
dues à Carson et van der Pol. Mais, si elles sont mathématiquement
parfaitement rigoureuses, elles ne satisfont pas les physiciens,
car ou bien elles passent par la transformation de Laplace, ce qui
modifie complètement la question, ou bien elles éliminent la fonction
$\delta$ et ses dérivées et interdisent des méthodes dont le succès était
incontestable.
&
 %[English translation]

\end{tabular}

\end{center}
```

Comment: Consider (possible duplicates): [make bilingual or trilingual LaTeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137283/5764); [Independent left and right columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32154/5764)

Comment: @Werner: Thanks a lot. Those two links solve my problem. I have voted to close this question. One might also want to read http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200159/5590 for the margin problem in the `paracol` package.