# Is there a way to display annotations/commentaries alongside original text?

Tags: formatting, marginnote

I have a text composed of source material and commentary or annotations on the source material. I want a way to display both the source material and the annotations/commentaries side-by-side in a book. I want it to be something like, source material on the left and annotations on the right, with different fonts to make it clear that one is source material and the other is annotation.

What I envision is something similar to a Tosafot, which is the Jewish  Talmud  displayed side-by-side with commentary (picture below).

I've explored [Margin Notes](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Margin_notes), but it isn't sufficient for my needs. The commentary can be a page long. I need LaTeX to produce something like a Tosafot.

Is it possible to develop such a system on LaTeX?

[image: Tosafot, the Jewish Talmud displayed side-by-side with commentary]

Comment: Welcome. // Some ways to explore wrt your question: a) check the links to the right ("Related"), b) search on this site, e.g. for tags, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marginnote c) check directly on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote , d) look up the topic it's categoriesd in and explore the topic, notes in this case: https://www.ctan.org/topic/notes .

Comment: you might want to check the package `paracol` as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137292/244141)

Comment: Paracol looks intriguing! Thanks I'll explore that.

Comment: MS-SPO, thank you, from the list you shared, versonotes seems to be the most viable.

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141924/how-to-typeset-a-complex-layout-like-a-page-of-the-talmud useful.

Comment: Thank you! Seems quite similar to what I need.